# com.force.api without passing the access_token getting the data, why?

Tags: java, salesforce, force.com

I am calling the salesforce using REST API provided by maven dependency.

```
<!-- Force REST API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.frejo</groupId>
    <artifactId>force-rest-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.39</version>
</dependency>
```

I have implemented the below code, but I am wondering without sending the access_token how am I getting the result ? Isn't that not secure or how its implemented ? Will be good to go ahead with this API?

```
public class ForceApiExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForceApi api = new ForceApi(new ApiConfig()
                .setUsername("XXX@xy.com")
                .setPassword("XXX")
                .setClientId("XXXXXMB8EGsF3NRtJ0")
                .setClientSecret("XXX"));

        ApiSession session = api.getSession();
        String accessToken = session.getAccessToken();
        System.out.println("ACCESS_TOKEN : "+accessToken);


        List<Map> result = api.query("SELECT name FROM Account").getRecords();
        System.out.println("RESULT : "+result.size());
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN : 00D7F0000001I8v!ARgAQB8tHuuquPRL5Z4uj4TBJG0cg0dJYBxy00jPhioEWKI86RlHqgXKSM0DfSTWHYVLl5i9HbbPxjXlgxlUP7XmLKejKrP4
RESULT : 535
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `Salesforce` internally provides the client the `authentication token` when a request is made. For `REST` API `Salesforce` uses [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/) for authentication. There exists different kinds of `OAuth` authentication process. One of them is through User credentials. When you are sending the request using the user credentials you are actually asking `Salesforce` to provide you the access token. After getting the request `Salesforce` verifies the credentials and sends the access token back. But here no refresh tokens can be used because the user does not directly authorize the app.

Follow [Understanding Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) link for more details.

Comment: hhmm. Could you please share some code snippet to support your answer ? Then I will accept this ans